# nameerror: Name Cover_Letter is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a script that automates making a cover letter.  I'm using Python 3.6 and am getting the NameError: Name cover_letter is not defined.  Cover_letter in this case is an argument inside the function call.  What would cause this to throw a NameError?

```
from sys import argv
from fpdf import FPDF
import json
import csv

def write_cover_letter(cover_letter, skills):

    # open csv file and read input
    with open(skills) as skills_csv:

        reader = csv.reader(skills_csv)
        rownum = 0

        for row in reader:

            pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4')  # portrait mode, mm , A4 size paper
            pdf.add_page()  # new blank page
            pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)  # font, Style (B,U,I) , fontsize in pt.

            #ignore the header row
            if rownum == 0:
                pass

            else:
                model_cover_letter = open(cover_letter, 'r')


                for line in model_cover_letter:

                    line = line.replace('#website', row[0])
                    line = line.replace('#inserttools', ','.join(row[1].split('#')))  # skills are seperated by '#' split and join them
                    line = line.replace('#toolproficient', row[2])
                    line = line.replace('#toolyr', row[3])
                    line = line.replace('#company', row[4])

                    pdf.write(6, line)

                pdf.output('cover_letters/Cover Letter - ' + row[4] + '.pdf', 'F')
                pdf.close()

            rownum = rownum + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # just use the right file names or modify the ones provided
    write_cover_letter(cover_letter, skills)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this all the code you're using? Because you didn't define `cover_letter` before calling the function, exactly as the error message is telling you. There's not much to be said beyond what the error message said.

Comment: You should declare a  variable before you are going to use it. In your condition without declaring cover_letter, skills you are using it in your main function. So declare it before using .

Answer (score 1):

When you call your `write_cover_letter` function you cannot pass cover_letter as you haven't assigned a value to it. Instead pass the string of the filename for your model cover letter file

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It seems kind of weird to me that I have to define an argument in a function.  How would be best to do this?  Could I write it something like 
with open(skills) as skills_csv:?

Comment: Whenever you pass an argument to a function you are passing something physical, whether that be a reference to a python object or a value. What you are trying to pass is whatever is attached to the label 'cover_letter'. As you haven't given a value or reference for the label 'cover_letter' python does not know what you want to send to the function. If you were wanting to attach a value to the label before passing it to your function simply add `cover_letter = 'yourfilenamehere'` before the function call

Answer (score 1):

Take a more careful look at the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 46, in <module>
    write_cover_letter(cover_letter, skills)
NameError: name 'cover_letter' is not defined
```

The error is on the 46th and final line of the file, where you call `write_cover_letter` with `cover_letter` as an argument. `cover_letter` is defined inside the function, but that call is outside the function.

To make the program work, you'll need to provide some other value for the function to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If i put the last line inside the function it no longer errors but doesn't run.  What other value could I give it to have it run?  If I define cover letter outside of the function it also gets rid of the error but doesn't run.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Judging by the comment on line 45, you should put in the name of the cover letter file (relative to wherever you are running the program), something like `"cover_letter.file"`.